# How to center drawable in togglebutton via setButtonDrawable (programmatically...)

Tags: android, togglebutton

How do I center the content of an togglebutton without any text inside specified ?

It's a togglebutton without text, but for images for each state.

Edit: Well, I ended up implementing my own ToggleImageButton.

Comment: refer [This](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/05/20/create-custom-toggle-button-android/)it might be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

```
togglebutton.buttonDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(yourContext, R.drawable.your_drawable)
```

or in your xml

```
<ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

My solution for this is to use **[CompoundButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)**.

A button with two states, checked and unchecked. When the button is pressed or clicked, the state changes automatically.

I do it as my own class (extend CompundButton) and than in init function,

```
this.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cell_toggle));
```

cell_toggle.xml (classic selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent"  />
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/bright_sky_blue"/>
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `setButtonDrawable` for `ToggleButton` is not works well.
I use `FrameLayout` with `ToggleButton` and `ImageView` inside. Looks good but you have to use `android:translationZ` for the `ImageView` for put `drawable` on the top.

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/type0"
                android:text=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:onClick="onClickToggle"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:translationZ="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/type_0"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
```